# Convert strings to 16Bit UTF integers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, hashcode, utf-16, 16-bit

I'm working with firebase firestore and for some reason I need to hash every new user document ID to integer specifically a **16Bit UTF integer**. Mostly it's an attempt at duplicating the **.hashcode** method in Dart.

what I have found and tried is this

```
// Convert to 32bit integer
const hashFunction = (string) => {
  var hash = 0;
  if (string.length == 0) return hash;

  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    char = string.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = (hash << 5) - hash + char;
    hash = hash & hash;
  }
  return hash >>> 0;   // returns hash as positive integer
};
```

but this only converts to 32bit int. Any and all help is appreciated.

EDIT1: Using @selbie's changes i made some progress but the hash i'm getting is quite different from the .hashCode method in Dart[image: this is dart's output] and [image: this is JS output]

is there anyway i can get thesame result

Comment: " I need to hash every new user document ID to integer" - why do you think you need to do this? And why are you doing this client-side?

Comment: what datatype is the variable `hash` supposed to be? int16? int32? uint32? uint16? something else?

Comment: @Dai actually i'm doing this via a cloud function on the sever

Comment: @Thomas uint16 i think

Comment: `2328644` ain't a 16 bit value. That are at least 22 bits. Where did you get the source code for your `hashFunction` from? I wasn't able to locate that function in the dart repo.

Comment: @Thomas the .hashCode method is inbuilt in Dart and that is what i'm trying to replicate using Javascript so that i can arrive at the same output

Answer (score 4):

If you only want a 16-bit hash, then:

Instead of this:

```
return hash >>> 0;   // returns hash as positive integer
```

This:

```
return hash & 0xffff; // return lower 16-bits of hash value
```

This line:

```
if (string.length == 0) return hash;
```

Isn't needed since your for-loop will simply not run if string.length is 0.

Finally, not a good idea to have a variable name the same as a type.  So let's just rename `string` to be `s`.

Here's a simplified solution:

```
const hashFunction = (s) => {
  var hash = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    hash = (hash << 5) - hash + s.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = hash & hash; // prevent overflow from happening
  }
  return hash & 0xffff;   // returns lower 16-bit of hash value
};
```

With that in mind, a 16-bit hash isn't a very strong hash. There are sure to be collisions after a few thousand strings are hashed.  Consider a crytographically strong hash or a larger hash width as appropriate.

Comment: `return hash & 0xffff` depends, this basically returns a uint16. If you want a (signed) int16 it would be `return (hash<<16)>>16;`